How can I rewrite nginx linux blazor wasm standalone
I have a server path:
/usr/share/nginx/html/wwwroot

Hello I have rewrite multi paths
 server {
        listen 80; 
        server_name  test.local.80;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/wwwroot/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            types {
                application/wasm wasm;
            }
            default_type application/octet-stream;

            location /myblazorapp/_framework/ {
                gzip_static on;
            }
            
        }
       location /app1/test{
              proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
            } 
        location /(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            } 
    } 

}

but got the following error.
open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/app1/test" failed (2: No such file or directory).
I tested on nginx on windows it works fine, but on linux it fails.
